# Date not showing after paste

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report file, in some section i am copying a table from a remote computer into local excel file, but after copy date's are not like date, i need to search & replace everytime ( search "." replace with "." )then dates comes. I have a vba code but not correcting in all sheets.

```
Sub tarihecevir()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim fnd As Variant
    Dim rplc As Variant

    fnd = "."
    rplc = "."

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
                          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next sht
End Sub
```

It works with normal ctrl+H but macro doesnt fix it.
Please help me.

Comment: Can't you just format the range as a Date e.g. sht.Range("A2:D50") = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")

Comment: Need to do it in macro, i have macro running for report, after all need to change "." with "."

Comment: ... and what's the difference between `fnd` and `rplc`?